# Is there a way we can have "React Redux" Provider and Consumer in a Mix - React and Non React (Riot) Application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, riot.js

**Objective**: Trying to migrate Riot + Redux application to React + Redux application in chunks

**Challenge**: Accessing Redux store in migrated components

This is **How i tried**:

1. Proving store at root Riot ( Non-React) component:

   ```js
   function stateProviderReact() {
     ReactDOM.render(
       <Provider store={store}>
         <ReactAppRoot/>
       </Provider>,
       document.getElementById('kickstartReactId')
     )
   }
   ```

   Here:
   ReactAppRoot: Dummy/Empty container having connect method with the intention to have store access to all react components.

   kickstartReactId:

   ```js
   <div id="kickstartReactId">
       <riot-page if={ isReady } shouldShowHeader={ isCapable } />
   </div>
   ```
2. Accessing store in react class components like:

   ```js
   const { config, storeProp, end } = this.props
   ```

   ```js
   <ReactReduxContext.Consumer>
     {({ store }) => console.log({store})}
     <ReactComp storeProp={ storeProp } config={ config } end={ end } />
   </ReactReduxContext.Consumer>
   ```

Any lead will be appreciated ! Thanks !

Comment: Wha... i mean... what made you want to use redux? it's a cool word, sounds impressive, but it's a pile of.... @#$!@.... seriously... normal pub-sub and simple encapsulation of the api access will do everything you want and better.

Comment: redux is already in use with existing riot application.